# IOS AudioQueue doesnt play when enqueue packets late

Tags: ios, audioqueue

I have an app that enqueues packets to AudioQueue, and it's working perfectly. The problem is when I have a delay in the network, and I can't serve packets in time to AudioQueue.

All the application is working well and the enqueueBuffer doesnt return any error, but AudioQueue is discarding packets (so I have no sound), because they are too old.

Can I force AudioQueue to play those audio packets?, or at least, know that the packets are being discarded?. Because if I know it, i can do Pause-Play to restart the Queue... (not very good solution, but I haven't anything better)

Because the delay could be very big, I can't use a big buffer, because this would minimice error, but not solve it

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right track. You can handle network delays by detecting in your callback procedure when you have reached the end of your network buffer, then pausing the AudioQueue. Later on, restart the queue once enough packets have been buffered. Your code would look like this

```
if playerState.packetsRead == playerState.packetsWritten {
    playerState.isPlaying = false
    AudioQueuePause(aq)
}
```

And in your network code

```
if (playerState.packetsWritten >= playerState.packetsRead + kNumPacketsToBuffer) {
    if !playerState.isPlaying {
        playerState.isPlaying = true

        for buffer in playerState.buffers {
            audioCallback(playerState, aq: playerState.queue, buffer: buffer)
        }

        AudioQueueStart(playerState.queue, nil)
    }
}
```

You would also need to update your code so that every time you receive a packet from the network, `playerState.packetsWritten` is incremented, and similarly for `playerState.packetsRead` when you add a packet to the audio queue. The optimal number for `kNumPacketsToBuffer` depends on the codec and network conditions. I would recommend using 256 for AAC and adjusting up/down based on performance.

Comment: Thank you very much. Thats very usefull information. It would be great if I could force to play all packets (without discarding at all). But at least, that's a good idea.

Comment: Pausing the queue won't cause the packets to be discarded. Audio Queue maintains an internal timeline (which you can retrieve using `AudioQueueGetCurrentTime:`) that continues to advance even in the absence of any packets being played. When you enqueue a buffer with packets older than the current time, those packets get discarded. Pausing the queue also pauses the timeline so if you pause before running out of packets, then resume playback once you receive the delayed packets, those packets won't be considered old and will be played back correctly.